# Counting in a List of objects with Linq, between 2 dates

Tags: c#, linq, list, date, count

I'm trying to count objects in a list. My code looks like this:

```
var count = tempMessages
                 .Where(MessageDate => MessageDate > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-6))
                 .Count();
```

As you can see, I'm trying to count Messages where the MessageDate is max 6 seconds old. But I am getting this error message :

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'ChatProj.Models.Message' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: the error does tell you your mistake. you are trying to compare your `object` with a `datetime`. I think you are missing declaring the property of `MessageDate` i.e. `MessageDate.Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tempMessages` is an enumerable of a custom class `Message`, the `Where` class will take that as the parameter to the expression, so you need to access the date property within it:

<sub>There is also an overload on `Count` that can take an expression to save doing the `Where`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx</sub>

```
var checkDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-6);

var count = tempMessages
    .Count(message => message.Date > checkDate);
```

The error message highlights this, you are trying to say "is my message greater than this date", instead of "is the date of this message greater than this date".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help! Works now, looks like this: 

`var count = tempMessages.Where(Message => Message.MessageDate > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-6)).Count();`

Answer (score 2):

Because tempMessages is a list of type 'ChatProj.Models.Message and not DateTime, possibly there is a Date Property on Message so you can write this code:

```
var count = tempMessages.Where(Message => Message.Date > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-6)).Count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works now! Looks like this: 

`var count = tempMessages.Where(Message => Message.MessageDate > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-6)).Count();`